# Can someone please explain the meaning of two lines below in the program to implement pipe?

Tags: c, pipe, posix, ipc

Need explanation about what the writer is trying to do here.
Why cannot I use Single dimension array instead od 2d array?

```
char writemessages[2][20]={"Hi", "Hello"};
char readmessage[20];
```

Program snippet:

```
   int main() {
   int pipefds[2];
   int returnstatus;
   char writemessages[2][20]={"Hi", "Hello"}; //why can't i use singlr char array
   char readmessage[20];
   returnstatus = pipe(pipefds);

   if (returnstatus == -1) {
      printf("Unable to create pipe\n");
      return 1;
   }

   printf("Writing to pipe - Message 1 is %s\n", writemessages[0]);
   write(pipefds[1], writemessages[0], sizeof(writemessages[0]));
   read(pipefds[0], readmessage, sizeof(readmessage));
   printf("Reading from pipe – Message 1 is %s\n", readmessage);
   printf("Writing to pipe - Message 2 is %s\n", writemessages[0]);
   write(pipefds[1], writemessages[1], sizeof(writemessages[0]));
   read(pipefds[0], readmessage, sizeof(readmessage));
   printf("Reading from pipe – Message 2 is %s\n", readmessage);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably because they want to send the two messages separately? Hard to tell without seeing the whole code...

Comment: there's an issue: "you" send `writemessages[0]` and `writemessages[1]` but always specify the `sizeof(writemessages[0])`.

Comment: @Aif there is no issue, `sizeof(writemessages[0])` and `sizeof(writemessages[1])` are both equal to 20, you probably confuse `sizeof` and `strlen`

Comment: @bruno: that is correct! Although from a "reviewer" point of view, it *looks* like a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> explain the meaning of two lines below

The line

```
char writemessages[2][20]={"Hi", "Hello"};
```

defines an array of characters having 2 rows of 20 columns and initializes it, because of the null character to end the strings the array can contains 2 strings having up to 19 characters excluding the null character.

The initialization makes the first string to be `'H'` `'i'` then the null char, and the second `'H'` `'e'` `'l'` `'l'` `'o'` then the null char

This is a short way equivalent to :

```
char writemessages[2][20]={ { 'H', 'i', 0 }, { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 }};
```

or

```
char writemessages[2][20]= {
   { 'H', 'i', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
   { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
};
```

The line

```
char readmessage[20];
```

defines an array of size 20 so allowing up to 19 characters more the null character.

> Why cannot I use Single dimension array instead od 2d array?

this is just a choice to group them in a 2 dimensional array, you can also use single dimension arrays :

```
 char writemessage1[20] = "Hi";
 char writemessage1[20] = "Hello";

 printf("Writing to pipe - Message 1 is %s\n", writemessage1);
 write(pipefds[1], writemessage1, sizeof(writemessage1));
 ...
 printf("Writing to pipe - Message 2 is %s\n", writemessage2);
 write(pipefds[1], writemessage2, sizeof(writemessage2));
```

Note the code send always 20 characters, changing the definitions to have

```
 char writemessage1[] = "Hi";
 char writemessage1[] = "Hello";
```

`write(pipefds[1], writemessage1, sizeof(writemessage1));` sends 3 characters and `write(pipefds[1], writemessage2, sizeof(writemessage2));` sends 6 characters because of the size of the arrays (they are automatically sized and initialized to contain the ending null character)

---

probably

> ```
> printf("Writing to pipe - Message 2 is %s\n", writemessages[0]);
> write(pipefds[1], writemessages[1], sizeof(writemessages[0]));
> ```

must be

> ```
> printf("Writing to pipe - Message 2 is %s\n", writemessages[1]);
> write(pipefds[1], writemessages[1], sizeof(writemessages[1]));
> ```

to send "Hello" rather than again "Hi"